# How do i get the footer to stick to the bottom

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page)

I have this [page](http://projects.posnation.com/) and if you log in with

username: john
password: tester

you will see the footer is not sticking to the bottom...any ideas on how to do this...i was thinking of using a min-height on the middle container but that doesnt work for large monitors unless i make it very high...any ideas..

here is my html

```
<body class="index_projects en production controller_projects">
    <div class="shell">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="container" class="container"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer-wrap"></div>
</body>
```

any idea what i maybe doing wrong

Comment: Your last tag should be </body> instead of </div>.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at this post [Get down! How to keep footers down](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page)

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your css:

```
#footer-wrap
{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 75px;
    z-index: 1;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

This is how I did it for a project of mine. As far as I remember "z-index: 1" is there so that the footer would pass over other page elements in case the browser window would be very small, and "zoom: 1" is to fix something with IE. You could also try without these styles. Adjust the height to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it with css :

```
#footer {
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;//or absolute if you want it above the contents
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

And in your HTML page :

```
<div id="footer">
  <div id="footer-wrap">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This blog post from is also worth mentioning:

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/10/05/full-height-app-layouts-a-css-trick-to-make-it-easier/